# Use PHP to find a string inside a string and get some values from it

Tags: php, regex, string, strpos

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'this is some random text 
  <div class="myClass" title="myTitle">this is some random text
  again</div> and some more randome text';
```

Now I would like to remove this content from it:

```
<div class="myClass" title="myTitle">this is some random text again</div>
```

But at the same time I would like to store the value of class and the value of title

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Do you have always a div with class myClass?

Comment: yes, that's how I find out what I'll do with it

Comment: See [How to parse and process HTML/XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample script for what your example shows specifically:

```
<?php
  $string = 'this is some random text <div class="myClass" title="myTitle">
             this is some random text again</div> and some more randome text';
  preg_match('/class=\"(\w{1,})\"\stitle=\"(\w{1,})\"/i', $string, $matches);
  echo "Class: {$matches[1]}\n";
  echo "Title: {$matches[2]}\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
marks-mac-pro:~ mstanislav$ php regex.php 
Class: myClass
Title: myTitle
```

You may have to adjust for other uses and/or ensure compatibility with naming conventions of HTML attributes.